# Facebook Page Tab app not appearing to non-page admin users

Tags: facebook-apps

I am experiencing a problem similar to 2 others who have recently written about this issue.

A newly created Page Tab Facebook app displays for admin users but not for regular users.
I only have 8 page tabs currently so it cannot be that there are too many.
Also, sandbox mode is disabled ( have tried both enabled and disabled).

Can anyone think  of a reason that this might be occurring?

I added the tab with the code:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Could it have something to do with https in the url as opposed to http?

I am at a loss and do not know how to go about solving this issue.

Any ideas, however far-out they may be,would be aprreciated.

Thank you to anyone who might think they can help...

Answer (score 3):

Have you forgotten to take the app out of Sandbox Mode? (try toggling it just in case, even if it's not in sandbox mode, as this is by far the most likely explanation here)

Also, check there aren't demographic restrictions set on the app or page via the API, as in this case only the users that meet the restrictions will see the tab. (though the admins will always see it)

Also check that you've configured the Page Tab URL and Secure Page Tab URL settings for the app correctly, as if a user uses HTTPS and the App doesn't support it they won't see the tab

If the tab isn't appearing at all it's almost certainly one of those two problems ,if it's displaying but the content isn't rendering, also check your code and make sure it's not fataling on checking the `signed_request` for non-admins or something like that

Comment: What's your app ID? my answer covers ~90% of cases where someone reports this issue